# SimpleSDAudio Error 48 meaning

Tags: audio, arduino

I'm trying to play a certain audio file from an SD card using Arduino UNO clone, but I got Error 48 on both of the microSD cards I've tried. Can you please explain to me what does the Error 48 stand for and how to fix it? Thanks

**EDIT**: I found the meaning in the library files: `No valid MBR/FAT-BS signature found in sector 0`. I still don't know how to fix it tho :/

Answer (score 0):

No valid MBR/FAT-BS signature found in sector 0.